# The method setData(Bundle) in the type Message is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Tags: multithreading, optimization, handler

There are many ways to create threads, The most simplest way I know to create a thread is the following:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //thread work here
    }
});
```

I am looking for the shorthand version for creating a message being sent to a Thread Handler-class;

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("KEY", "DONE");
Message msg = (new Message());
msg.setData(bundle);
msg.obtain(handler.obtainMessage());
handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

I think the Shorthand would be something like the following:

```
new Message().setData(new Bundle().putString("KEY","DONE")).obtain(handler.obtainMessage());
```

but for '.setData' I get the error;

> The method setData(Bundle) in the type Message is not applicable for
>   the arguments (void)

What are my options experts?

NOTE: This implementation is for Android OS.

Comment: What is the return type of the `.obtain()` function?

Comment: returns Message() type.

Comment: Are you sure? The error message you’re getting from the compiler suggests that it returns void.

Comment: I imagine its because the constructor has not been fully called, so the whole object doesn't exist fully yet. I know if I put the new Message with obtain,there is no error. I even tried the reverse and putting obtain before setData and the compiler named the same error, tried; (new Message()).obtain(handler.obtainMessage()).setData(new Bundle().putString("KEY","DONE");